# Any suggestions for a Ruby on Rails plugin for the new Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Apart from the obvious references to facebooker and rfacebook. Mainly for sign-ons and getting basic profile info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an excellent response on Quora

http://www.quora.com/Any-suggestions-for-a-Ruby-on-Rails-plugin-for-the-new-Facebook-API

Depending on which style you like, top 3 from RubyGems list, based on no of downloads as on Aug 3, 2010

http://rubygems.org/search?query...

fb_graph (0.2.1)
A Ruby wrapper for Facebook Graph API
1421 downloads
http://rubygems.org/gems/fb_graph

koala (0.8.0)
Koala is a lightweight, flexible Ruby SDK for Facebook. It allows read/write access to the socia...
1347 downloads
http://rubygems.org/gems/koala

fgraph (0.3.2)
Ruby Facebook Graph API
771 downloads
http://rubygems.org/gems/fgraph

rest-graph
A super simple Facebook Open Graph API client
1275 downloads
http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-graph

Answer (score 0):

You've named the two big gems for Facebook integration, both have their good and bad points.

If you are looking for a lightweight method of handling logins and basic information, I'd try the [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage) service. For the same development effort of getting Facebook integration going you could get a handful of other services as well. They have a free and a very reasonable (considering the development time it offsets) pay option.